# Uploading a file to a library with curl - how do you also update the column values

Tags: lookup-column, file-upload, linux

I'm able to upload files from linux to sharepoint using something like this
 curl  -u "Domain\Account":'Password'  --ntlm -k   -T  report.xls   https://portal.company.com/test_site/test_doc/

I would like to update a column name client with a switch like

-f "client=myclient" or -d "client=myclient"

But I can't seem to make it work.  Is there anyway to use curl update a library column?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cURL job to invoke SharePoint REST services after uploading the document.  The SharePoint REST services would allow you to update the document metadata.  I don't have a specific example directly using SharePoint, but there are lots of resources out there about invoking REST services with cURL.

[cURL and REST Services](https://drupal.org/node/1795770)